# jqGrid is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsp

Im new to front-end development and Im having a TypeError of jqGrid is not a function when trying to display a jqGrid on my JSP file.

here is the actual error from the console screen:

```
<anonymous> property.htm:959
[10]</</ae.Callbacks/c() app.js:5
[10]</</ae.Callbacks/d.fireWith() app.js:5
[10]</</<.ready() app.js:6
s() app.js:4
```

If I remove the app.js script from my jsp then the jqGrid comes up but removing this app.js breaks many other parts in the form. Has anyone been able to use jqGrid with app.js?

Comment: What is `app.js`? and also, why do you use `jqGrid`, there is a lot of better libraries out there...can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Hi Hackerman, app.js seems to be compliation of javascript libraries, Im truly not sure as this is a min file and has lots of unreadable code. We use jqGrid because this is the technology that was implemented by our main developer. What other libraries would you recommend for creating Grids?

Comment: http://js-grid.com/demos/ http://backgridjs.com/#complete-example https://www.dynatable.com/ http://square-bracket.com/openjs https://datatables.net/ http://www.pontikis.net/labs/bs_grid/demo/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that grid.locale-en.js and jquery.jqGrid.min.js were being included 2 times in the JSP. As soon as I removed the duplicate script it worked perfectly.